# Python Unit Test Mocking

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

If you have seen my other question you will know I am having a very hard time at the moment with unit tests in Python. Two days of trying and I've made no progress.

In my method which is part of a Class there is several calls to a DAL.

```
car_registration = self.dal.cars.get_by_registration('121D121')
```

This DAL is configured in the base class. I want to completely overrid/mock these calls when running my unit tests and instead return predefined responses so I can continue with the method and ensure everything works as expected.

The method starts of with:

```
def change_registration(self):

    body = json.loads(self.request.body)
    registration = body['registration']
    car = self.dal.cars.get_by_registration(registration)
```

My Python test file at the moment is:

```
class CarTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
         self.car_controller = CarController()


     def test_change_registrations(self):
         self.car_controller.dal.cars.get_by_registration = MagicMock(return_value=3)
         response = self.car_controller.change_registration()
```

I am expecting to get the response 3. However, an error is being thrown.

> AttributeError: 'CarController' object has no attribute '_py_object'

It appears the mocking isn't working and it still trying to use the main DAL which isn't fully set up when using the unit tests. How do I prevent it for looking for the actual DAL but instead mocks?

Comment: I assume you need to mock the `dal` attribute itself. Something like `self.car_controller.dal = Mock()`. Then `self.car_controller.dal.cars.get_by_registration.return_value = 3`.

Comment: If I change that line I get the error `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not showing us the code that triggers the error because there is nothing wrong with your strategy. Using some imagination to mimic  code we don't have I can write this and it runs with no problem:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class CarList():
    def get_by_registration(self, registration):
        pass

class Dal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cars = CarList() 
    pass

class CarController:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dal = Dal()

    def change_registration(self):
        registration = None
        car = self.dal.cars.get_by_registration(registration)
        return car 

class CarTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
         self.car_controller = CarController()


     def test_change_registrations(self):
         self.car_controller.dal.cars.get_by_registration =\
             MagicMock(return_value=3)
         result = self.car_controller.change_registration()
         self.assertEqual(result, 3)

unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Personal opinion: I would suggest you to start simple. Use anything 'magic' once you understand what it provides you over the non-magic way. Using a non-magic solution tends to be easier to understand.

I think you have multiple simple solutions at hand. For what you tried to achieve, instead of:

```
self.car_controller.dal.cars.get_by_registration = MagicMock(return_value=3)
```

You could try:

```
self.car_controller.dal.cars.get_by_registration = lambda: 3
```

But you mentioned you want to replace all methods. In fact I would consider a 'simple' dependency injection. If you find it difficult to test, it might be a sign that the another design would be better (that's the idea of TDD - Test Driven Design). A simple dependency injection is one where you for example just pass `dal` to the constructor of `CarController`.

Here is a complete example with some variations of the test:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock

class SomeDal(object):
    def get_something(self):
        return 'something'

class SomeController(object):
    def __init__(self, dal):
        self.dal = dal

    def upper_something(self):
        return self.dal.get_something().upper()

class TestSomeController(TestCase):
    def test_using_simple_patch(self):
        controller = SomeController(SomeDal())
        controller.dal.get_something = lambda: 'anything'
        assert controller.upper_something() == 'ANYTHING'

    def test_using_simple_patch_and_injection(self):
        dal = SomeDal()
        dal.get_something = lambda: 'anything'
        controller = SomeController(dal)
        assert controller.upper_something() == 'ANYTHING'

    def test_using_simple_mock_class(self):
        class MockDal(object):
            def get_something(self):
                return 'anything'
        controller = SomeController(MockDal())
        assert controller.upper_something() == 'ANYTHING'

    def test_using_semi_magic_mock(self):
        mock_dal = Mock(spec=SomeDal)
        mock_dal.get_something.return_value = 'anything'
        controller = SomeController(mock_dal)
        assert controller.upper_something() == 'ANYTHING'
```

Comment: The only reason I used MagicMock was because I came across an example online. I'm still very confused as to how I should be doing this. I'm not sure if I should have self. because its a member of the CarController Class and not the test Class for example.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of examples in the internet. I've added some simple examples to give you some ideas. BTW I prefer `pytest` over `unittest` - no need for inheritance. But it's a minor detail. I'm not saying not to use Mock or MagicMock. But use it when you understand why you should use them.

Comment: if you use self inside the TestCase class it can look as you are mocking the TestCase and not CarController, but as you write self.car_controller... this is a reference to a CarController object so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here my example:

```
# test_tool_file.py
import unittest

from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, call

import test_tools_file

class MyObject():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def count(self):
        return len(self.get_data())

class TestFile(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Cas de tests.
    """
    @patch("test_tools_file.MyObject.get_data")
    def test_1(self, mock_get):
        """ test_1
        """
        mock_get.return_value = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

        obj = MyObject(["12", "13"])

        result = obj.count()

        self.assertEqual(result, 6)
```